# How to avoid nested for loops in Matlab for better cpu time

Tags: matlab

I should calculate this formula for large value of p, so 4 nested loops made my code very slow and inapplicable. I will so thankful if anyone can help me for better implementation with use of sum and other suitable matlab commands!
**K(i,j)=sum(sum(a(m)*b(n)*A(i,j,m,n),m=1:p),n=1:p);
i,j,m,n ->1:p**
and A is 4D Matrix and a,b are vector.
Thank.

Comment: Please post the code that you have so far, or at least the relevant portion of that code.

Comment: And include a small example with desired input and output

Answer (score 0):

I can get rid of 2 of the `for` loops.  Perhaps one of the MATLAB wizards on this site can do better.

```
p = 3;

A = rand(p, p, p, p)
a = rand(p, 1)
b = rand(p, 1)

% I think your original code does something like this.
K1 = zeros(p, p);
for n = 1: p
    for m = 1: p
        for j = 1: p
            for i = 1: p
                K1(i, j) = K1(i, j) + a(m) * b(n) * A(i, j, m, n);
            end
        end
    end
end
K1

% This gives the same result, with half the loops.
K2 = zeros(p, p);
for n = 1: p
    for m = 1: p
        K2 = K2 + a(m) * b(n) * A(:,:,m,n);
    end
end
K2

% Verify that the two answers are the same.
all(K1(:) == K2(:))
```

Comment: Thank you Dear Jeff, your solution improve my code very good! but do you belive that one can remove the other remaining loops?

Comment: and for general case such as K1(i, j) = K1(i, j) + a(m) * b(n) * A(i, m, j, n); (index of A matrix is not Consecutive) the suggested procedure can not implement like K2 = K2 + a(m) * b(n) * A(:,m ,:,n);

Comment: It does work for non-consecutive indices, but you have to use `squeeze(A(:,m,:,n))`.  I suspect that the remaining loops could be eliminated with `bsxfun` or `repmat`, but I am not sure.